# Relación Muchos a Muchos

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Windows Forms estoy usando EF code first tengo una relación muchos a muchos, muestro código.

Map Proveedor:

```
public ProveedorMap()
    {
        ToTable("Proveedores");
        HasKey(c => c.ProveedorId);
        Property(c => c.ProveedorId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(c => c.ProveedorId).HasColumnOrder(0);
        Property(c => c.RazonSocial).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200).HasColumnOrder(1);
        Property(c => c.NroDocumento).HasMaxLength(11).HasColumnOrder(2);
        Property(c => c.DocumentoIdentidad).HasColumnOrder(3);
        Property(c => c.Direccion).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(4);
        Property(c => c.Fijo).HasMaxLength(9).HasColumnOrder(5);
        Property(c => c.Celular).HasMaxLength(9).HasColumnOrder(6);
        Property(c => c.Representante).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(7);
        Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(8);

        HasMany(c => c.Modelos)
            .WithMany(c => c.Proveedores)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("ProveedorId");
                mc.MapRightKey("ModeloId");
                mc.ToTable("ProveedorModelo");
            });
    }
```

Map Modelo:

```
public ModeloMap()
    {
        ToTable("Modelos");
        HasKey(c => c.ModeloId);
        Property(c => c.ModeloId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(c => c.ModeloId).HasColumnOrder(0);

        HasRequired(c => c.Categoria).WithMany(c => c.Modelos).HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoriaId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        Property(c => c.CategoriaId).IsRequired().HasColumnOrder(1);

        Property(c => c.Descripcion).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnOrder(2);
    }
```

Método

```
public void AsignarModelos(Proveedor proveedor, List<EntidadesDominio.Modelo> modelos)
    {
        using (PosContext Context = new PosContext())
        {
            //Marcamos la Marca para que no reciba cambios
            Context.Entry(proveedor).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            if (proveedor.Modelos == null)
                proveedor.Modelos = new List<EntidadesDominio.Modelo>();

            //Recorremos cada Proveedor que se quiera asociar
            modelos.ForEach(x =>
            {
                //El Proveedor tampoco debe recibir cambios
                Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                //Asociamos a la coleción de Proveedores el nuevo item
                //Este si recibira cambios
                proveedor.Modelos.Add(x);
            });

            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Quiero guardar la entidad Proveedor y la lista de modelos que envío, pero me sale el siguiente error:

> "Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY \"FK_dbo.ProveedorModelo_dbo.Proveedores_ProveedorId\". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos \"PosDb\", tabla \"dbo.Proveedores\", column 'ProveedorId'. Se terminó la instrucción."}

Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[ProveedorModelo]([ProveedorId], [ModeloId])
VALUES (@0, @1)
',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=0,@1=1
```

Imagen
[image: ProveedorModelo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo de la siguiente manera :

Antes de todo lo que hago es crear la lista de modelos, después creo el `Proveedor` y enseguida le asigno al Proveedor la lista de modelos.

Muestro código

```
Proveedor _proveedor = new Proveedor();
                _proveedor.ProveedorId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProveedorId.Text)
                    ? 0
                    : Convert.ToInt32(txtProveedorId.Text);
                _proveedor.RazonSocial = txtRazonSocial.Text.Trim();
                _proveedor.NroDocumento = txtNroDocumento.Text;
                _proveedor.DocumentoIdentidad = ((EnumDocumentoEdentidad)(cboTipoDocumento.SelectedValue));
                _proveedor.Direccion = txtDireccion.Text;
                _proveedor.Fijo = txtFijo.Text;
                _proveedor.Celular = txtCelular.Text;
                _proveedor.Representante = txtRepresentante.Text;
                _proveedor.Email = txtEmail.Text;
                List listRowCheck = GetChecked(dgvModelo, "colSN");
                _repositoryProveedor.InsertOrUpdate(_proveedor); =>Creo Proveedor
                _repositoryProveedor.AsignarModelos(_proveedor, listRowCheck); =>Asigno lista de modelos a Proveedor
                txtProveedorId.Text = Convert.ToString(_proveedor.ProveedorId);
                Opener.HabilitarBotonesDespuesGuardar(true);
                Actualizar();
```

En las líneas que estan en **negrita** primero creo el `Proveedor` y a continuación asigno la lista de modelos. Previamente había creado los modelos.